# SFINAE to Selectively Include Member

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, decltype

I am trying to write a template class which may or may not define a particular member function depending on its template parameter type. Further the return type of this member function depends on the return type of of a member of the template paramter (if defined).

Below is a minimal example of my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct has_foo_int {
private:
    template <typename U>
    static decltype(std::declval<U>().foo(0), void(), std::true_type()) test(int);
    template <typename>
    static std::false_type test(...);
public:
    typedef decltype(test<T>(0)) test_type;
    enum { value = test_type::value };
};

template <typename T, bool HasFooInt>
struct foo_int_return_type;

template<typename T>
struct foo_int_return_type<T,false> {};

template<typename T>
struct foo_int_return_type<T,true> {
    using type = decltype(std::declval<T>().foo(0));
};

template<typename T>
struct mystruct
{
    T val;

    //auto someMethod(int i) -> decltype(std::declval<T>().foo(0)) // error: request for member ‘foo’ in ‘std::declval<double>()’, which is of non-class type ‘double’
    //auto someMethod(int i) -> typename foo_int_return_type<T,has_foo_int<T>::value>::type // error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct foo_int_return_type<double, false>’
    template<typename R=typename foo_int_return_type<T,has_foo_int<T>::value>::type> R someMethod(int i) // error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct foo_int_return_type<double, false>’
    {
        return val.foo(i);
    }
};

struct with_foo_int {
    int foo(int i){
        return i+1;
    }
};

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    mystruct<with_foo_int> ms1;
    cout << ms1.someMethod(41) << endl;

    mystruct<double> ms2;

    return 0;
}
```

What I would like to happen is that the code compiles fine and outputs 42 for `ms1.someFunc(41)`. I would also expect that if one accidentally tried to call `someFunc` on `ms2` that it would fail to compile.

Unfortunately each of the alternatives I have tried has failed. The first and second, I think I understand why they wouldn't work.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164750/problem-with-sfinae) that SFINAE only works for template functions so I tried giving a dummy template parameter to work out the return type but this too fails in the same way.

I'm clearly not understanding something here, what am I missing? Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

*P.s. I'm using g++ 4.7.3*

*P.p.s I have also tried `std::enable_if` but get much the same results as with my `foo_int_return_type` struct.*

Comment: The function itself needs to take the relevant parameter as a template argument, otherwise there's no substitution at the call-point and you don't get SFINAE. A popular workaround is a dummy parameter like `template<class U = T, *insert SFINAE here with U instead of T*>`

Comment: It works! I'm not sure why though, if you post this as an answer and explain it I'll happily accept.

Comment: For SFINAE, the compiler (or the user) need to deduce (provide) a type that the compiler will later try to **S** ubstitute and **F** ail

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yes, and that's the role I thought `R` should be playing here.

Comment: @Dan: No, the expression triggering SFINAE needs to depend on a template parameter *of that function*.

Comment: @Dan: `R` is a single type, it is either provided or deduced, but after that type is resolved there is no **substitution**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short, tidy and documented way of doing what you are attempting,
with some possible bugs addressed thereafter.

```
#include <type_traits>

/*
    Template `has_mf_foo_accepts_int_returns_int<T>`
    has a static boolean public member `value` that == true
    if and only if `T` is a class type that has a public
    member function or member function overload 
    `int T::foo(ArgType) [const]`  where `ArgType`
    is a type to which `int` is implicitly convertible.
*/
template <typename T>
struct has_mf_foo_accepts_int_returns_int {

    /* SFINAE success:
        We know now here `int *` is convertible to
        "pointer to return-type of T::foo(0)" 
    */
    template<typename A>
    static constexpr bool test(
        decltype(std::declval<A>().foo(0)) *prt) {
        /* Yes, but is the return-type of `T::foo(0)`
            actually *the same* as `int`?...
        */
        return std::is_same<int *,decltype(prt)>::value;
    }

    // SFINAE failure :(
    template <typename A>
    static constexpr bool test(...) {
        return false; 
    }

    /* SFINAE probe.
        Can we convert `(int *)nullptr to 
        "pointer to the return type of T::foo(0)"?
    */
    static const bool value = test<T>(static_cast<int *>(nullptr)); 
};

template<typename T>
struct mystruct
{
    using has_good_foo = has_mf_foo_accepts_int_returns_int<T>;

    T val;

    /*  SFINAE:
        `template<typename R> R someMethod(R)` will be this if and only
        if `R` == `int` and `has_good_foo` == true.         
    */
    template<typename R = int>
    typename std::enable_if<
        (has_good_foo::value && std::is_same<R,int>::value),R
    >::type 
    someMethod(R i) {
        return val.foo(i);
    }

    /*  SFINAE:
        `template<typename R> R someMethod(R)` will be this if and only
        if `R` != `int` or `has_good_foo` != true.      
    */
    template<typename R = int>
    typename std::enable_if<
        !(has_good_foo::value && std::is_same<R,int>::value),R
    >::type
    someMethod(R i) {
        static_assert(has_good_foo::value && std::is_same<R,int>::value,
            "mystruct<T> does not implement someMethod(R)");
        return i;
    }
};

// Testing...

#include <iostream>

struct with_foo_int
{
    int foo(int i) {
        return i + 1;
    }
};

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    mystruct<with_foo_int> ms1;
    cout << ms1.someMethod(41) << endl;

    mystruct<double> ms2;
    cout << ms2.someMethod(41) << endl; // static_assert failure

    return 0;
}
```

This solution faithfully reproduces a couple of possible loopholes in your
own attempt as posted:-

**1)** It looks as if you may believe that evaluating `std::declval<U>().foo(0)` is
a SFINAE way of determining whether `U::foo` exists and takes a single argument 
of type `int`. It doesn't. It is merely a SFINAE way of determining whether
`U::foo(ArgType)` exists where `ArgType` is anything to which `0` is
implicitly convertible. Thus `ArgType` could be any pointer-or-arithmetic
type, not just `int`.

**2)** You may not have considered that `std::declval<U>().foo(0)` will be satisfied
if either *or both* of `U::foo(ArgType)` `U::foo(ArgType) const` exists. You
may well care whether you call a `const` or a non-`const` member function on
`U`, and you would certainly care which of two member function you call. If
`with_foo_int` were defined as:

```
struct with_foo_int
{
    int foo(int i) const {
        return i + 1;
    }
    int foo(int i) {
        return i + 2;
    }   
};
```

then the solution given would call the non-`const` overload and 
`ms1.someMethod(41)` would == `43`.

2) Is easily dealt with. If you wish to ensure that you can only call
`T::foo(ArgType) const` then add a `const` qualifier to `mystruct::someMethod`.
If you don't care or wish only to call `T::foo(ArgType)` then leave things
as they are.

1) is a little harder to solve, because you must craft a SNIFAE probe for
`T::foo` that is satisfied only if it has *the right signature*, and that
signature will either be `const` qualified or not. Let's assume you want
`int T::foo(int) const`. In that case, replace template 
`has_mf_foo_accepts_int_returns_int` with:

```
/*  Template `has_mf_foo_arg_int_returns_int<T>
    has a static boolean public member `value` that == true
    if and only if `T` is a class type that has an un-overloaded
    a public member `int T::foo(int) const`.
*/ 
template< typename T>
struct has_mf_foo_arg_int_returns_int
{
    /* SFINAE foo-has-correct-sig :) */
    template<typename A>
    static std::true_type test(int (A::*)(int) const) {
        return std::true_type();
    }

    /* SFINAE foo-exists :) */
    template <typename A> 
    static decltype(test(&A::foo)) 
    test(decltype(&A::foo),void *) {
        /* foo exists. What about sig? */
        typedef decltype(test(&A::foo)) return_type; 
        return return_type();
    }

    /* SFINAE game over :( */
    template<typename A>
    static std::false_type test(...) {
        return std::false_type(); 
    }

    /* This will be either `std::true_type` or `std::false_type` */
    typedef decltype(test<T>(0,0)) type;

    static const bool value = type::value; /* Which is it? */
};
```

and in template `mystruct` replace:

```
using has_good_foo = has_mf_foo_accepts_int_returns_int<T>;
```

with:

```
using has_good_foo = has_mf_foo_arg_int_returns_int<T>;
```

(Template `has_mf_foo_arg_int_returns_int` is adapted
from [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10707822/1362568) and
you can read how it works there.)

What you gain in SFINAE-precision from the latter approach comes at
a price. The approach requires you to attempt to take the address of `T::foo`,
to see if it exists. But C++ will not give you the address of an overloaded
member function, so this approach will fail if `T::foo` is overloaded.

The code here will compile (or appropriately `static_assert`) with 
GCC >= 4.7.2 clang >= 3.2.